# Will the other directories on my C drive still be visible?

Tags: windows-7

My Windows 7 ate itself, corrupted a few files, now refuses to boot.  On the same drive were other directories of various assorted non-Microsoft applications I like to use.  After the crash, I have been mounting those from outside (as F:[whatever]).

If I go ahead and reinstall Windows 7 on that drive and use the drive again as my primary, will those other directories be visible to it from inside?  Meaning if I boot up my new installation of Windows from within that drive, will I be able to see those other old directories via Windows Explorer on the C drive (where any haven't been run over by the reinstalled OS)?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Uesr225626 - You should ask these questions on superuser.com as they are not programming related.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, as long as you don't format the drive as part of the Windows 7 installation. Just pay close attention to the initial install questions...

Before you start, though, it might make sense to copy them from their current location (F:?) to another drive or even the current boot drive to mitigate your risk of losing them via an inadvertent format during the install.